# Relations, Discrete Structures

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Looks like this question was worded a bit different than my previous questions I've worked through, and understand. I'm having issues determining what S is.

Given the set *A = {1, 2, 3}* and the set *S = {(x, y) | x and y in A}*.

Consider the relation ≤ defined on S as follows: (*(x1, y1) ≤ (x2, y2) if x1 ≤ x2 and y1 ≤ y2*. Draw the directed graph of this relation. Show that it is a partial order. Explain why it is not a total order.

The part I don't quite understand is that *((x1,y1) <= (x2,y2)*

it then specifies IF *x1 <= x2 and 1y <= y2* which makes a little more sense so I kept pulling different elements from A, and came up with.

**S = (1,1) (2,2) (1,2) (2,3)(2,1) (3,2) (3,3)** but I don't know if I'm doing this correctly, as I think there might be two requirements for (x,y) to be in S, but I might have just used one.

[image]

(Second image might be wrong, but kinda the idea)

2. Let A = {0, 1, 2, 3}. Define a relation R on A as follows:
   R = {(0, 0), ((1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)}.
   Draw a directed graph for this relation and identify which of the following properties hold for this relation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the set of *all* ordered pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ such that $x,y\in A$. Since $A$ has $3$ elements, there are $3^2=9$ ordered pairs in $S$:

$$S=\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 3,1\rangle,\langle 3,2\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle\}\;.$$

As you can see, you missed $\langle 1,3\rangle$ and $\langle 3,1\rangle$.

Any relation on $S$ is going to be a subset of $S\times S$, so it’s going to be a set of ordered pairs of the ordered pairs in $S$. The problem then goes on to define a relation $\le$ on $S$. Any relation on $S$ is going to be a subset of $S\times S$, so it’s going to be a set of ordered pairs of the ordered pairs in $S$. I think that part of your confusion may be due to the fact that the same symbol, $\le$, is being used for the relation on $S$ that is used for the ordinary relation of *less than or equal to* used in comparing integers, so I’m going to use a slightly different symbol for it: $\preceq$. I’ll repeat the definition using this new symbol:

> Consider the relation $\preceq$ defined on $S$ as follows: $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\preceq\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$ if $x_1\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y_2$.

Notice that $\preceq$ is a relation between ordered pairs of elements of $A$, not between elements of $A$. Specifically, if $x_1,x_2,y_1$, and $y_2$ are elements of $A$, then we say that the pair $\langle x_1,y_1$ is in the relation $\preceq$ to the pair $\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$ if two things are true: $x_1\le x_2$, **and** $y_1\le y_2$. For instance, $1\le 1$ and $2\le 3$, so $\langle 1,2\rangle\preceq\langle 1,3\rangle$; here $x_1=x_2=1$, $y_1=2$, and $y_2=3$. Similarly, $\langle 2,1\rangle\preceq\langle 3,2\rangle$ (because $2\le 3$ and $1\le 2$), and $\langle 2,1\rangle\preceq\langle 2,1\rangle$ (because $2\le 2$ and $1\le 1$), but $\langle 2,1\rangle\not\preceq\langle 1,1\rangle$, because in the first coordinate $2\not\le 1$.

We’re writing $\langle 1,2\rangle\preceq\langle 1,3\rangle$ and so on because that relational notation is easier to read than the technical definition of $\preceq$ as

$$\preceq\;=\left\{\big\langle\langle x_1,y_1\rangle,\langle x_2,y_2\rangle\big\rangle\in S\times S:x_1\le x_2\text{ and }y_1\le y_2\right\}\;;$$

it’s easier to make sense of $\langle 1,2\rangle\preceq\langle 1,3\rangle$ than to make sense of $\big\langle\langle 1,2\rangle\preceq\langle 1,3\rangle\big\rangle\in\;\preceq$. But $\preceq$ is still a subset of $S\times S$, so it relates *pairs* of elements of $A$, not elements of $A$.

Because $S\times S$ has $9$ elements, your directed graph is going to have either $9$ or $18$ vertices, one or two for each ordered pair of elements of $A$, depending on how you’ve been taught to draw it. It will have a directed edge from a vertex $\langle 1,2\rangle$ to a vertex $\langle 1,3\rangle$, for instance, because $\langle 1,2\rangle\preceq\langle 1,3\rangle$. It won’t have a directed edge from a vertex $\langle 1,3\rangle$ to a vertex $\langle 1,2\rangle$, because $\langle 1,3\rangle\not\preceq\langle 1,2\rangle$: $3\not\le 2$. And it won’t have a directed edge in either direction between $\langle 1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,1\rangle$; why? (This observation should help you to answer the last part of the question.)

Comment: Makes sense! so S={⟨1,1⟩,⟨1,2⟩,⟨1,3⟩,⟨2,1⟩,⟨2,2⟩,⟨2,3⟩,⟨3,1⟩,⟨3,2⟩,⟨3,3⟩} as you mentioned above, I was correct in my process, minus missing (1,3) and (3,1) right?

Comment: @beatles1235: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @beatles1235: Yes. That’s precisely why I changed $\le$ to $\preceq$ for the relation being defined on $S$: to emphasize that it is *not* the ordinary $\le$ relation on $A$. I could simply have called the relation $R$ and written, for instance, $\langle 1,2\rangle\mathrel{R}\langle 1,3\rangle$.

Comment: And one more clarification, I'm not using S={⟨1,1⟩,⟨1,2⟩,⟨1,3⟩,⟨2,1⟩,⟨2,2⟩,⟨2,3⟩,⟨3,1⟩,⟨3,2⟩,⟨3,3⟩} in my drawing am I?

Comment: @beatles1235: You mean the drawing of the directed graph? Depending on how you’ve been taught to draw the graph, you’ll have either $9$ or $18$ vertices. If it’s $9$, there will be one for each of those members of $S$, and you’ll label it with that member. If it’s $18$, which makes the graph a lot easier to draw, you’ll have two for each of those members of $S$, again labelled accordingly.

Comment: Okay. I don't know why but I'm still a little confused on how I derived S lol. I essentially picked two numbers from A (lets say (1,2) ) and plugged them into the if x1 ≤ x2 and y1 ≤ y2.. was that the correct process? Sorry if I'm asking dumb questions! I'm just trying to ensure I know what I'm doing for the second problem

Comment: @beatles1235: The definition of $S$ has nothing to do with the definition of the new relation. $S$ is the set of all ordered pairs $\langle x,y\rangle$ such that $x$ and $y$ are elements of $A$. Start with $x=1$; then $y$ can be $1,2$, or $3$ (i.e., any element of $A$), and you get the ordered pairs $\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 1,2\rangle$, and $\langle 1,3\rangle$. Now set $x=2$ and do the same thing; you get the next three pairs in the listing of $S$ in my answer. Finally, set $x=3$, the last remaining possibility, and repeat to get the last three ordered pairs.

Comment: Okay, and once I have all order pairs (9 in total) I then use the ⪯={⟨⟨x1,y1⟩,⟨x2,y2⟩⟩∈S×S:x1≤x2 and y1≤y2} to determine if they are in the new relation. Right?

Comment: @beatles1235: That’s right.

Comment: Thank you!!! You've helped me out a ton!

Comment: @beatles1235: You’re welcome!

Comment: If you're still around, I went through and plugged each pair into the ⪯ and I and up getting ⪯ S = (1,2) (1,3)(2,2)(2,3)(3,2) (3,2) (3,3) (2,1) (1,1) (3,1) too. So now I draw it out?

Comment: @beatles1235: You’re misunderstanding $\preceq$, I think. Let me ask you a question: if I tell you that $\langle 1,3\rangle\preceq\langle x,y\rangle$, can you list the pairs that $\langle x,y\rangle$ could be?

Comment: (1,3) ⪯ (1,3) also (1,3) ⪯ (2,3) and (1,3) ⪯ (3,3) right?

Comment: @beatles1235: Yes, that’s correct. The list for $\langle 1,1\rangle$, on the other hand, includes all $9$ members of $S$, and the list for $\langle 3,3\rangle$ includes only $\langle 3,3\rangle$.

Comment: So do I need to a separate drawing for each pair? What I suppose I'm getting stuck on is with (1,1) since all 9 members of S are included as you said. So I was putting each pair I tested into the same list, which eventually gave me the same pairs S had.

Comment: @beatles1235: No, you’ll have a single drawing with a whole lot of arrows in it. I’d draw part of it, except that I don’t know which of two approaches you’re being taught; I’d have to see an example from the text that you’re using.

Comment: I uploaded one on the main question, I'll also show you one that I did for a previous example that gave me what the relation was, and asked to draw it so determine its properties

Comment: I've addded the question that was asked, as well as my own drawing (based off the first picture)

Comment: @beatles1235: Okay: you’re going to have $9$ vertices, and the graph is going to be a bit of a mess — you should use a full sheet of paper and arrange the vertices more or less in a circle. You’ll have a loop at each vertex, because $\langle x,y\rangle\preceq\langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in A$: the relation is reflexive. You’ll have arrows from $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to each of the other eight vertices. You’ll have arrows from $\langle 1,3\rangle$ to each of $\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle$, and $\langle $3,3\rangle$. And so on.

Comment: Each pair is a vertex correct?

Comment: @beatles1235: Yes, that’s right, so you’ll have $9$ vertices.

Comment: Put a picture below so it's less confusing

Comment: @beatles1235: It’s the right kind of drawing, but it’s missing quite a few arrows (e.g., from $\langle 2,3\rangle$ to $\langle 3,3\rangle$, and it has some that it shouldn’t (e.g., from $\langle 2,3\rangle$ to $\langle 1,3\rangle$: $\langle 2,3\rangle\not\preceq\langle 1,3\rangle$, since $2\not\le 1$). I’ll be away for a few hours now, but I’ll check back when I get home.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Updated my picture below!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my updated drawing again! I've added that it's reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive which is why it would be a partial order. Hopefully i'm corret
[image]

Here's another question I started working on:
2.  Consider the set S defined in problem 4 and the following relation = defined on S as follows: (x1,y1) = (x2, y2) if x1 + y1 = x2 + y2. Draw the directed graph of this relation. Show that it is an equivalence relation. List its equivalence classes.
[image]
I believe so far so good, but I'm having issues on describing how this is a equivalence relation.

Comment: Almost: you’re missing four arrows that I can see on my way out the door: from $\langle 1,2\rangle$ to $\langle 2,3\rangle$, $\langle 2,1\rangle$ to $\langle 3,2\rangle$ and $\langld 3,3\rangle$, and $\langle 2,2\rangle$ to $\langle 3,3\rangle$. The way you’ve set it up, in addition to the loops, you should have arrows from each vertex to each vertex that is below it, to its right, or below and to its right.

Comment: Updated! I don't know if its correct yet, but I just wanted to say thank you so much. I had absolutely no Idea on how to approach this at all, and whether it's 100% at this point or not, I don't know, but i'm grateful at how patient you've been with me! It's been quite a few years since I've taken any sort of math class since I joined the military, so i'm trying to get back into it!

Comment: I didn’t check every single arrow in the first graph, but it looks okay now. You’re having trouble seeing that the second is an equivalence relation because you’ve got some of the arrows wrong. There shouldn’t be arrows in either direction between $\langle 2,1\rangle$ and $\langle 1,3\rangle$, for instance, because $2+1\ne 1+3$. There *should* be arrows both ways between $\langle 3,1\rangle$ and $\langle 2,2\rangle$, because $3+1=2+2$. You should end up with $5$ equivalence classes, one for the pairs with $x+y=2$, one for those with $x+y=3$, and so on up to $x+y=6$. And you’re very welcome.

Comment: Got it! My final question  I think know what makes it NOT an equivalent relation would help me understand. Assuming it's still the arrows that I have in the current pictures, why would it not be an equivalent relation right now?

Comment: What you have right now in the lower picture isn’t transitive. For instance, you have an arrow from $\langle 2,2\rangle$ to $\langle 1,3\rangle$ and another from $\langle 1,3\rangle$ to $\langle 3,1\rangle$, which is correct, but none from $\langle 2,2\rangle$ to $\langle 3,1\rangle$: that’s a violation of transitivity.